# Create index for all columns in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, indexing

I am developing an application in C# that dynamically creates a table using a user entered query. The syntax I use for this is:

```
CREATE TABLE <table name> (<user query>)
```

Is there a way I can add an index to the table that includes all columns without specifying the exact column names. Something like this would be great but this doesn't work:

```
CREATE INDEX <index name> ON <table name> (*)
```

Alternatively, is there a way I query for the columns in the database. If I have this information then I can build up the query using the exact column names to add an index after the table is created.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding indexes to every column doesn't make sense.  Database schema aren't meant to be designed through automation.

Comment: Why are you indexing all columns? Usually this does not make that much sense.

Comment: see this answer, it explains why you shouldn't index all columns : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447987/why-cant-i-simply-add-an-index-that-includes-all-columns

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
SHOW [FULL] COLUMNS FROM <table name>
```

to get the columns