# Optimising read performance by INCLUDEing all columns in index when key is known

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, database-performance

Say I've got the following table:

```
FileExtension (PK)
ContentType
ContentSubType
IsAllowable
```

I know it's *always* going to be retrieved by FileExtension. Should I add an index on FileExtension and INCLUDE the other columns? I don't care about insert/update performance.

Will such an index perform better for retrieve operations than just a clustered primary key?

I've considered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447987/why-cant-i-simply-add-an-index-that-includes-all-columns) but it refers to a scenario where the lookup key is not known.

Comment: Does your table have a clustered index? If so, what is it?

Comment: No, just a primary key (is that equivalent to a clustered index?)